# Cohort in Excel with aggregated monthly data

Tags: excel, pivot-table, retention

I'm trying to make a cohort in Excel Pivot with a dataset having:

aggregated number of monthly sign ups (month by month), aggregated number user of completed next step, number of months between sign up and the next action taken.

What I can't figure out when i do the pivot to have the cohort, is what to put into the value field in the pivot? Normally I would take the Customer `IDs` as value, but since I only have the data on aggregated monthly level I'm not sure if i put the number of sign ups or the number of next step completed?

Also how do I get the sum of each cohort so i can calculated the retention rate?

I hope this make sense.

Signup month    Action completed month  Months between sign up and action completed signups conversion to Action completed

```
Jan-17  Sep-18  20  95  71
Jan-17  Jan-18  12  95  77
Jan-17  Jun-18  17  96  72
Jan-17  Jan-18  12  92  78
Jan-17  Dec-18  23  91  78
Jan-17  Jul-18  18  100 73
Jan-17  Oct-18  21  92  79
Jan-17  Feb-18  13  95  70
Jan-17  Jan-18  12  91  79
Jan-17  May-18  16  93  71
Jan-17  Jun-18  17  95  72
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to achieve?

[image]

REVISION #1

This layout shows the total number of signups, by the month in which the signup occurred, distributed by the number of months btwn the signup and action completed.  The action completed month may be omitted and will still achieve the same result; it is there FYI only.

[image]

REVISION #2

This is an example of the average months between the signup and action.  Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, this is partly what i need, see my comment below :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. 
The problem is that not all sign ups in a month turning into an action taken. So that's why i need both actions taken and sign ups in the same pivot. So month 0 (between sign up and action taken) = all sign ups in that month, while month 12 for instance = users from Month 0 that took an action etc, month 13 = users from Month 0 tthat took an action. In best case then i will be able to show how long it takes for users to take an action.

Comment: That's what this pivot shows.  The grand total is the total signups for Jan 2017.  The sample data does not have a month 0 scenario; the earliest action completed month is Jan 2018.  For example, the data shows that in the month of Jan 2017 there were 1035 total signups.  278 of the signups (of the 1035 total signups) took 12 months to achieve the action completed status; 95 of the 1035 took 13 months, etc.  Are you instead trying to calculate one grand total average?